# NSPredicate with Core Data to find if elements in an array are the same

Tags: arrays, core-data, nspredicate

How can I write a NSPredicate that will check if all the elements in an NSArray are the same? I need this for a more complex predicate that I am using to filter NSTableView.

Answer (score 0):

`NSPredicate` can't tell you if all the items are the same, but you could use it to filter an array for objects that are not equal to object[0]. This wouldn't be particularly performant since it would have to check the entire contents of the array.

You could instead use `- (void)enumerateObjectsWithOptions:` then bailing out when you find a different object via `*stop = YES`.

Consider looking at using `NSSet`, since that is designed to store a collection of unique objects (albeit unordered).

Without knowing more detail it's impossible to say what is the best solution for you.